# Expanding a JSON column in R

Tags: json, r, csv

I am reading in a data table from a CSV file. Some elements in the CSV are in JSON format, so one of the columns has JSON formatted data, for example:

```
       user_id   tv_sec        action_info
  1:   47074     1426791420    {"foo": {"bar":12345,"baz":309}, "type": "type1"}
  2:   47074     1426791658    {"foo": '{"bar":23409,"baz":903}, "type": "type2"}
  3:   47074     1426791923    {"foo": {"bar":97241,"baz":218}, "type": "type3"}
```

I would like to flatten out the action_info column and add the data as columns, as follows:

```
       user_id   tv_sec        bar     baz    type
  1:   47074     1426791420    12345   309    type1
  2:   47074     1426791658    23409   903    type2
  3:   47074     1426791923    97241   218    type3
```

I am not sure how to achieve this. I found a library to convert strings to JSON in R (RJSONIO) but I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do next. When I experiment with just trying to convert all rows in the `action_info` column to JSON with the command `userActions[,.(fromJSON(action_info))]` I basically get a data table with what seems like all the values accumulated in some way that's not entirely clear to me. For example, running that with my (non-example) data I get:

```
                                                    V1
1: 2.188603e+12,2.187628e+12,2.186202e+12,1.164000e+03
2:                                               type1
Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(encoding)) return(0L) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(i)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

So, I'm trying to figure out:

1. how to operate on the column to convert it from JSON to values (I think I am doing this correctly though, but I'm not certain)
2. how to get the values and create columns out of them in either the current or new data table.

Comment: You see the error because `action_info` is a `factor` not a string. You can either use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you read your data or simply convert it to characters `as.character(df$action_info)` afterwards and then use `fromJSON`.  Problem is that it is simply not a valid JSON. Is it your exact data?

Comment: It's not my exact data. I have fixed the JSON to be valid; my apologies for the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue in my data though and fixed it there as well. Now I am no longer getting that error. Editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather ugly but should work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

lapply(as.character(df$action_info), RJSONIO::fromJSON) %>% 
    lapply(function(e) list(bar=e$foo[1], baz=e$foo[2], type=e$type)) %>% 
    rbindlist() %>%
    cbind(df) %>% 
    select(-action_info)
```

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(structure(list(user_id = c(47074L, 47074L, 47074L), tv_sec = c(1426791420L, 
1426791658L, 1426791923L), action_info = c("{\"foo\": {\"bar\":12345,\"baz\":309}, \"type\": \"type1\"}", 
"{\"foo\": {\"bar\":23409,\"baz\":903}, \"type\": \"type2\"}", 
"{\"foo\": {\"bar\":97241,\"baz\":218}, \"type\": \"type3\"}"
)), .Names = c("user_id", "tv_sec", "action_info"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Here's one way to do it with `data_table`:

```
df[, c('bar', 'baz', 'type'):=as.list(unlist(fromJSON(action_info[1]))),
   by=action_info]
```

How it works:

The `by=action_info` essentially makes sure we just call `fromJSON` once per unique `action_info` (once per row in your case); this is because `fromJSON` doesn't work on vectorised input.

The `fromJSON(action_info[1])` converts the `action_info` to JSON (the `[1]` is on the off chance that you have multiple rows with the same `action_info` since `fromJSON` doesn't work on vector input).

The `unlist` flattens the nested "foo: {bar...}" (do `fromJSON(df$action_info[1])` and `unlist(fromJSON(df$action_info[1]))` to see what I mean).

The `as.list` converts the result back into a list, with one element per "column" (`data.table` needs this to do the multiple assignment)

Then the `c('bar', 'baz', 'type'):=` assigns the output back out to the columns.

Note we don't match by name, so 'bar' is always the first part of the JSON, 'baz' is always the second, etc. If your `action_info` could have a `{bar: ..., baz: ...}` as well as a `{baz: ..., bar: ...}` the `baz` of the second will be assigned to the `bar` column. If you want to be cleverer and assign by name, you will have to think of something cleverer (for you could do `as.list(...)[c('foo.bar', 'foo.baz', 'type')]` to ensure the elements are in the right order before assigning).