# R: Expanding a multilayered JSON

Tags: r, json, dataframe, multiple-columns

Let´s assume that my dataframe looks like this:

[image: dataframe screenshot]

I have this multi-layered json string `response` in a column of the data frame and I would like to expand or parse its multiple columns in the same dataframe.

```
"[
{\"question\":
 {\"id\":314123,
  \"text\":\"What did you see in this module?\",
  \"question_id\":151,
  \"requirements\":
  {\"answer_type\":\"text\",
   \"text_required\":true}
  },
 \"response\":
 {\"free_text\":
  {\"id\":\"314123_ft\",
   \"text\":\"Identifying critical knowledge\"}
 }
},
{\"question\":
 {\"id\":314124,
  \"text\":\"What do you feel is the gap?\",
  \"question_id\":152,
  \"requirements\":
  {\"answer_type\":\"text\",
   \"text_required\":true}
 },
 \"response\":
  {\"free_text\":
   {\"id\":\"314124_ft\",
    \"text\":\"Knowledge is clearly mapped out\"}
 }
},
{\"question\":
 {\"id\":314125,
  \"text\":\"Which of the modules you need to focus on\",
  \"question_id\":153,
  \"requirements\":
  {\"answer_type\":\"text\",
   \"text_required\":true}
 },
 \"response\":
 {\"free_text\":
  {\"id\":\"3141125_ft\",
   \"text\":\"preparation of key knowledge\"}
 }
}
]"
```

I apologise if the indentation is not totally correct, as I did indent it manually from a single-line string.

Following other entries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599299/expanding-a-json-column-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742571/parse-multi-level-json-file-in-r), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57488048/r-json-multiple-columns) I have tried several methods, but none of them could expand the whole thing into new columns, getting different errors that I show here (I intentionally only chose the options with smaller number of lines in the code to keep the post small).

```
> fromJSON(df) %>% 
+   unnest(c(response))
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fromJSON’ for signature ‘"data.frame", "missing"’


>  df <- df %>% 
+    rowwise() %>%
+    do(data.frame(fromJSON(.$response, flatten = T))) %>%
+    ungroup() %>%
+    bind_cols(df %>% select(-response))
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

I would appreciate the help of any JSON expert on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach using `map` to convert your column of json strings to a list column of dataframe plus some additional wrangling using `tidyr` to unnest the nested dfs:

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble(
  id = 1:2,
  response = c(response, response)
)

df |> 
  rename(id1 = id) |> 
  mutate(
    response = map(response, jsonlite::fromJSON)
  ) |> 
  unnest_longer(response) |> 
  unnest_wider(response) |> 
  unnest_wider(c(response, question)) |> 
  unnest_wider(c(requirements, free_text), names_sep = "_")
#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#>     id1     id text    question_id requirements_answer_…¹ requirements_text_re…²
#>   <int>  <int> <chr>         <int> <chr>                  <lgl>                 
#> 1     1 314123 What d…         151 text                   TRUE                  
#> 2     1 314124 What d…         152 text                   TRUE                  
#> 3     1 314125 Which …         153 text                   TRUE                  
#> 4     2 314123 What d…         151 text                   TRUE                  
#> 5     2 314124 What d…         152 text                   TRUE                  
#> 6     2 314125 Which …         153 text                   TRUE                  
#> # ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​requirements_answer_type, ²​requirements_text_required
#> # ℹ 2 more variables: free_text_id <chr>, free_text_text <chr>
```

**DATA**

```
response <- "[
{\"question\":
 {\"id\":314123,
  \"text\":\"What did you see in this module?\",
  \"question_id\":151,
  \"requirements\":
  {\"answer_type\":\"text\",
   \"text_required\":true}
  },
 \"response\":
 {\"free_text\":
  {\"id\":\"314123_ft\",
   \"text\":\"Identifying critical knowledge\"}
 }
},
{\"question\":
 {\"id\":314124,
  \"text\":\"What do you feel is the gap?\",
  \"question_id\":152,
  \"requirements\":
  {\"answer_type\":\"text\",
   \"text_required\":true}
 },
 \"response\":
  {\"free_text\":
   {\"id\":\"314124_ft\",
    \"text\":\"Knowledge is clearly mapped out\"}
 }
},
{\"question\":
 {\"id\":314125,
  \"text\":\"Which of the modules you need to focus on\",
  \"question_id\":153,
  \"requirements\":
  {\"answer_type\":\"text\",
   \"text_required\":true}
 },
 \"response\":
 {\"free_text\":
  {\"id\":\"3141125_ft\",
   \"text\":\"preparation of key knowledge\"}
 }
}
]"
```

Comment: I´m sorry, I have to retract my check as I´ve just realised that this implementation does not expand all the fields. For instance, the latest "text" per question that it is an open field where people can put their own free text as it can be seen in the different responses in question 314124 and 314125, ```"Knowledge is clearly mapped out\"```is part of a free text by the user that is not captured anywhere in the new dataframe.

Comment: When I run my code with the provided example data the answers on the free text questions appear in column `free_text_text`.

Comment: I apologise, you are right, my bad. Check is back. I wasn't understanding the logic but I do know after just checking the output of ```map```. Thank you @stefan.

Comment: Everything fine. And yes. Unnesting may result in long column names. The issue is that the same field names are used in multilple places, e.g. we have multiple `id` and `text` fields. When unnesting this will result in an error because of duplicated names. For that reason I renamed the `id` column in `df` and for the last unnest step prefixed with the upper level name via `names_sep = "_"` which resulted in `free_text_text`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, now I understand it even better. It would be great to have a standardized implementation of this in the library (I will submit feedback to authors), where it could subtract the structure out of the map, as you did for storing the new list of columns. Brilliant solution though.